# Show relationship data in bulk

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am writing an API and there are my topics and comments related to it. My wish is to show all the topics while also showing the comments belonging to the topics. I established the relationship with the hasMany option, but I am having trouble showing the data.

**Post Table**
[image: Post Table]

**Comments Table**

[image: Comments Table]

**Post Model**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Posts extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $fillable = [
        'post_id',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Users');
    }

    public function comment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comments', 'post_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Comments Model**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comments extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'post_id',
        'description'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Users', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Posts', 'post_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

*For example, when I shoot all of the topics below, I want the comments with the user ids. How do I customize this?*

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 10,
    "image": "https://lorempixel.com/800/400/cats/WhaleDevops/?43757",
    "description": "Et quia enim distinctio non qui laudantium voluptatem. Cumque minus cum pariatur necessitatibus. Repellat qui provident voluptatum ut. Et sapiente eaque eum ut. Repudiandae eveniet a harum ea totam consectetur. Facere facilis sunt et consequuntur sapiente. A aspernatur placeat tenetur et. Omnis quasi sunt nostrum et velit sint quia. Velit temporibus ut aut ea in repudiandae.",
    "created_at": "1999-04-11T17:37:42.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-08-08T10:41:28.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 2,
    "image": "https://lorempixel.com/800/400/cats/WhaleDevops/?53905",
    "description": "Quasi ab recusandae molestiae pariatur et ut. Harum dolorum illo aspernatur fugit sequi aut. Modi quasi voluptas ad maxime ducimus quia molestiae maiores. Pariatur quam quam officia expedita. Alias quas aliquid et.",
    "created_at": "1972-03-17T04:01:26.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-08-08T10:41:28.000000Z"
  },
```

Comment: is it your first table is post's table or just by a mistake? i thing first one will be comment table and 2nd table might be posts table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to read up on [Laravel Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources)

> When building an API, you may need a transformation layer that sits between your Eloquent models and the JSON responses that are actually returned to your application's users. Laravel's resource classes allow you to expressively and easily transform your models and model collections into JSON.

The documentation is well written and easy to follow. It should have everything you need.

You will need to read the [Writing Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#writing-resources) chapter, that explains how to handle relationships.

Answer (score 1):

You have to need make two changes.

1)Remove post_id from post table and place it in comment table.

2)Write the query

```
Post::with('comment','user')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved my problem by looking at the document about Resource.